# frame-ancestors error showing only for Microsoft Edge

Tags: outlook, microsoft-edge, outlook-addin, outlook-web-addins

I have an Outlook add-in published in the AppSource and customers are using it. Was there any changes with a newer version of Edge or Outlook for Mac? Or any known solutions? I'm now getting this error just on Windows 10 desktop Outlook (The "<domain>" is our actual domain):

```
The Content-Security-Policy directive 'frame-ancestors' does not support the source expression '~^[^.]+\.<domain>.com\.com$'
```

[image]

I thought maybe we had it configured incorrectly but its working in browsers and Mac desktop apps.

I can reproduce with

- Outlook for Microsoft 365 MSO(16.0.14326.20384) 32-bit
- Windows 10 Enterprise, v. 21H1, 19043.1165

Our add-in: https://appsource.microsoft.com/en-us/product/office/wa200002693?tab=overview

Steps to repro:

1. Select an email in your inbox and then open the add-in
2. Login - is there a way to safely share this info with you?
3. This should auth and take the user to the add-in experience, instead it shows this error in the console and redirects to our homepage (this is the fallback experience if there's an error on login)

Comment: Can you provide the link to your add-in on AppSource? And also exact repro steps to get the error/screenshot of error?

Comment: I added the details to the original post

Answer (score 0):

The CSP policy directive that is being used in the add-in is not related to the add-ins platform, but to the browser. This repros when you visit: https://outlook.junipersquare.com/outlook/redirect?openDialog=true in Chrome/Edge, and it will show the same error.

I believe you are using an incorrect  format, as the documentation specifies using a wildcard character and not full regex.

visit https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Content-Security-Policy/frame-ancestors to see the documentation for frame-ancestor